# CreateProcessW failed error:2 ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory Host key verification failed, jupyter notebook on remote server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost, jupyter, remote-server

So I was following a [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebooks-on-remote-servers-603fbcc256b3) to connect to my jupyter notebook which is running on my remote server so that I can access it on my local windows machine.

These were the steps that I followed.

On my remote server :

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Then on my local machine

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 *******@**********.de.gyan.com
```

But I am getting an error

```
CreateProcessW failed error:2
ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

How do I resolve this? Or is there is any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the DISPLAY variable set because you want to use VcXsrc or another X-Server in Windows 10 the workaround is to add the host you want to connect to your known_hosts file.
This can be done by calling

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa host.example.com | Out-File ~/.ssh/known_hosts -Append -Encoding ASCII;
```

Comment: Amazing.  This worked, though I have no idea what it means

Comment: It would be useful to add an explanation to this. Why does this work? What does it do?

Comment: I get an error `bash: Out-File: command not found`, any thoughts?

Comment: I can add the host with `ssh-keyscan -t rsa spsssrv02 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` instead, but then I get a whole different but related set of errors :p

Comment: Please use powershell. The "Out-File" is a powershell command and ensures that the key is appended using ASCII encoding.
If you add the key with the >> maybe some other encoding is used and this will break the known_hosts file.

Comment: It works because it works around this bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/pull/506.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [openssh docs](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1), the ssh client, which will usually prompt for a password on the command line, will try to show a GUI dialog for the user to enter his password, if `SSH_ASKPASS` and `DISPLAY` environment variables are set.

On windows however, this is not properly supported yet, as the needed `ssh_askpass` binary is missing, and also because this seems still pretty X11 oriented.

Git for windows however seemed to get it working properly.

Of course, if you are just interested in entering your password on the command line, make sure the variables are unset. With the information you provided, it is however impossible to answer why the variable was set in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the values of "environment variables" with the POSIX shell command "env".

Or you simply type `echo $DISPLAY` or `echo $SSH_ASKPASS`. May vary from shell to shell.

Another way to solve the issue could be to insert your public RSA key into the .ssh/authorized_keys file on the target system, but this might only work if you enter this systems's ID into your local known_hosts file first, as described above.

How to generate a RSA keypair: Use `ssh-keygen -t rsa ...`.

Regards,
Stefan B.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a ssh version <= 8.6.0-beta1. It will work by just updating to version 8.6.0-beta1+ in your **elevated powershell** by

```
choco upgrade openssh
```

You can check your version by

```
choco list -lo openssh  # -lo: --localonly
openssh 8.6.0-beta1
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using cygwin. There was an ssh.exe in the PATH c:\windows\system32\ssh.exe ahead of /usr/bin/ssh.  Fixing the PATH avoided the problem.

Edited /etc/profile and added a line like this near the end:

`PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same probelm when I connect remote Linux server with local Windows10 VScode.

CreateProcessW failed error:2
ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.

I solved this by upgrade OpenSSH to OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3.

1. Download OpenSSH from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases
2. Decompress to somewhere
3. Edit system environment variable 'PATH', and move it above old Openssh.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with a missing exe in the config file under .ssh folder. My config file pointing to GIT tool connect.exe and I didn't have GIT for windows installed and after installing GIT, the issue is resolved